# Difference in function definitions in xattr.h on ubuntu and OSX

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am trying to run homebrew on OSX, on a project that we know can be built on Ubuntu, but when attempting to run make all on OSX we are running into an issue where the functions are expecting an extra argument.

```
libattr/attr_copy_fd.c: In function 'attr_copy_fd':
libattr/attr_copy_fd.c:76:9: error: too few arguments to function 'flistxattr'
  size = flistxattr (src_fd, NULL, 0);
         ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from libattr/attr_copy_fd.c:25:0:
/usr/include/sys/xattr.h:75:9: note: declared here
 ssize_t flistxattr(int fd, char *namebuff, size_t size, int options);
```

From what I can tell this is due to how the file xattr.h is written for each OS,

the file on ubuntu is here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/xattr.h

while the apple version is here: https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4570.41.2/bsd/sys/xattr.h.auto.html

The functions in the apple version require an extra int option that the linux version does not, is there a way for me to compile using the linux version of this file with homebrew?

Comment: Just because two OSes are Unix-like does not mean they are source compatible at the API level. As you've seen, they are often not. Worse, they could be similar enough that code compiles fine, but different enough that it behaves incorrectly. For example, a parameter could have a compatible type but incompatible semantics. You typically have to modify source to have alternative code paths for each OS, often using preprocessor conditionals (`#if...`). Autoconf is one common mechanism for figuring out what the OS supports and setting up the macros to test in the source.

Comment: Somehow using the Linux version of xattr.h would fix nothing. The code might compile, but it would make the call incorrectly. It would fail to pass anything for the required `options` parameter. The macOS implementation of `flistxattr()` would nevertheless attempt to examine the `options` parameter it expects to have received. It will find an uninitialized junk value there, causing it to do who knows what.